# Recreate transaction log in solidity code

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, contract-invocation, bsc

[image]

I have this log and i want to code a solidity contract/function that would do the same.

What i understand reading this transaction is that WBNB contract (`0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c`) is the one emitting the event Deposit and the destination is `0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E` ie PancakeSwap router.

But when i read the code of WBNB contract the

`function deposit() public payable {balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value; Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);}`

deposits to msg.sender as destination, so the pancake router has to be the caller of this function, right ? If so how to do so ? + i think the purpose of this function is to send WETH from (my wallet or my contract) to the router, right ?

In the router contract i found this :

```
interface IWETH {
function deposit() external payable;
function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
function withdraw(uint) external;
}
```

Maybe that's what i need to use, i'm not sure...

I started writting pieces of code but it's my first time trying solidity and i struggle a bit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The event says the router is wrapping BNB into WBNB. It sends BNB and it gets WBNB.

Comment: Thanks, i don't understand how you saw that it was wrapping bnb ? since we only have the wbnb addres and routeur address. If you have some time this is the entire transaction i'm trying to recreate : https://bscscan.com/tx/0x004341293fe43d713ad550b59647dd92a5ade9485953d83da3f99e09fa9a7d62#eventlog

Comment: It is the functionality provided by the deposit function. You send Ether, it assigns you an equivalente in WETH (WBNB is a copy of WETH it should do the same).